# Streaming live PCM to web browser using HTML5 tag

Tags: cgi, fastcgi, audio-streaming, pcm, lame

I currently have an application which receives live, raw PCM data from a remote source via UDP.  I would like to stream this to a web browser through a simple, straight-forward HTML5 tag.  In researching this project, I've come across IceCast a number of times which, as near as I can tell, can be configured to take in raw PCM and serve up an MPEG audio stream, thereby fulfilling my needs.  However much this may or may not work with IceCast, though, I would like to implement my own, custom solution.

So, to phrase this question in more specific terms, is solving this problem as simple as LAME-encoding the raw PCM data as it arrives and passing it along via HTTP?  I imagine this working as a CGI/FastCGI application, but I am by no means wedded to this form of solution.  Is there any other magic going on behind the scenes with IceCast?  And, finally, to sanity check: there is no special "stream/file header" I would need to send first, right?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any extra headers required. However, the main extra thing that Icecast is doing which a CGI/FCGI application wouldn't be able to do (at least, not well) is distributing the stream to multiple concurrent listeners. That part's pretty tricky to do well; I'd advise you to use Icecast unless there's a compelling reason to avoid it.

Comment: How would the client know how to decode that raw PCM data without a WAV header or similar to set up the format?  I'm pretty sure an initial header block is necessary.  If not, can you tell me what browser-supported stream format supports raw PCM that may be decoded at any point?

Comment: Err... I meant, if you're encoding the PCM audio to MP3, then there's no headers required. Sending raw PCM over the Internet would be pretty wasteful; I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  I read the title of the question and was confused.

Comment: Now, let's say that I want to avoid using MP3...would it be possible to do achieve my goal by encoding to OGG or WAV?  I've been trying to research such a solution, to little effect...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use ogg for streaming pcm. It creates pages and this allows streaming YET still use a file container. 
but again this means firefox and chrome only. There is actually a audio api javascript. If you request the pcm data in chunks and buffer on client and feed it to the audio api, it could do the trick. This api is implemented for audio processing on client side. Again doent expect super awesome speed. https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html